Video stream source change using Python Flask and JS
I have the following server side route code for stream
movies_list = ['./mov1.mp4', './mov2.mp4', './mov3.mp4',]

@app.route("/video", methods=["GET"])
def video():
    headers = request.headers
    if not "range" in headers:
        return current_app.response_class(status=400)

    video_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("media", movies_list[0]))
    size = os.stat(video_path)
    size = size.st_size

    chunk_size = (10 ** 6) * 3 #1000kb makes 1mb * 3 = 3mb (this is based on your choice)
    start = int(re.sub("\D", "", headers["range"]))
    end = min(start + chunk_size, size - 1)

    content_lenght = end - start + 1

    def get_chunk(video_path, start, chunk_size):
        with open(video_path, "rb") as f:
            f.seek(start)
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        return chunk

    headers = {
        "Content-Range": f"bytes {start}-{end}/{size}",
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": content_lenght,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    }

    return current_app.response_class(get_chunk(video_path, start,chunk_size), 206, headers)

Also client side html page
<video width="720" controls>
  <source src="/video" type="video/mp4">
</video>

How can I send a request from the client side to the server so that it changes the source and starts playing?

you can always add <form> with <button> or some link <a> - with information that you want new content - but it need to reload all page. If you want it without reloading then you have to use JavaScript with fetch(url, ...) to send request

maybe you should use url with parameter - /video/<file_id> and use this file_id in flask to start streaming different file - and later you can use JavaScript to replace url in <source src="/video/other_id" > and browser should display different stream. And this may needs some buttons on page with some JavaScript code.

If you use url /video/<int:index> in Flask to select file by index
@app.route("/video/<int:index>", methods=["GET"])
def video(index):

    # ... use index to select file ...
    video_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("media", movies_list[index])) 

then you can use JavaScript to replace src= in <source> with different index and browser will load different stream.
video  = document.querySelector('video');
source = document.querySelector('video source');

source.src = '/video/1';
video.load();
video.play();


JavaScript with buttons can look like this:
<video width="720" controls>
  <source src="/video/0" type="video/mp4">
</video><br/>

<button onclick="change_stream(0)">VIDEO #1</button>
<button onclick="change_stream(1)">VIDEO #2</button>
<button onclick="change_stream(2)">VIDEO #3</button>

<script>
video  = document.querySelector('video');
source = document.querySelector('video source');

function change_stream(index) {
    console.log(`change source: ${source.src} -> /video/${index}`);
    source.src = `/video/${index}`;
    //video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();    
    video.play();
}       
</script>


Full working example:
I use render_template_string so everyone can easily copy and run code.
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', )
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<video width="720" controls>
  <source src="/video/0" type="video/mp4">
</video><br/>

<button onclick="change_stream(0)">VIDEO #1</button>
<button onclick="change_stream(1)">VIDEO #2</button>
<button onclick="change_stream(2)">VIDEO #3</button>

<script>
video  = document.querySelector('video');
source = document.querySelector('video source');

function change_stream(index) {
    console.log(`change source: ${source.src} -> /video/${index}`);
    source.src = `/video/${index}`;
    //video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();    
    video.play();
}       
</script>

</body>
</html>''')

movies_list = ['./mov1.mp4', './mov2.mp4', './mov3.mp4']

@app.route("/video/<int:index>")
def video(index):

    headers = request.headers
    if not "range" in headers:
        return app.response_class(status=400)

    video_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("media", movies_list[index]))
    size = os.stat(video_path)
    size = size.st_size

    chunk_size = (10 ** 6) * 3 #1000kb makes 1mb * 3 = 3mb (this is based on your choice)
    start = int(re.sub("\D", "", headers["range"]))
    end = min(start + chunk_size, size - 1)

    content_lenght = end - start + 1

    def get_chunk(video_path, start, chunk_size):
        with open(video_path, "rb") as f:
            f.seek(start)
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        return chunk

    headers = {
        "Content-Range": f"bytes {start}-{end}/{size}",
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": content_lenght,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    }

    return app.response_class(get_chunk(video_path, start,chunk_size), 206, headers)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()


@app.route("/video/<int:index>", methods=["GET"])
def video(index):
    # ... use index to select file ...
    video_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("media", movies_list[index])) 

It works, thanks

if it helped then you can mark my answer as accepted and later you can upvote it :)

@app.route("/video/<int:index>", methods=["GET"])
def video(index):
    # ... use index to select file ...
    video_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("media", movies_list[index])) 

and source change via JS by click button
It works, thanks

Stackoverflow is NOT normal forum but Q&A portal (one Question & many Answers) - and here is place for answer/solution, not for comments or thanks :) People may downvote this answer.
